# problem with  "count_all_results" and "where" with Active Record in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

In CodeIngiter User guide ,they said the following code:

```
$this->db->where('name', $name);
$this->db->where('title', $title);
$this->db->where('status', $status); 
// WHERE name = 'Joe' AND title = 'boss' AND status = 'active'
```

It means when I wanna select some thing from database by active record,I should use `where` method and it will do it by replace `AND` between fields.
now I wanna to make login page,I do this:

```
public function True_login($username = '',$password = '')
    {
        $this->db->flush_cache();
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
        $count = $this->db->count_all_results('PM_ADMIN_LIST');
        if ($count === 1)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

but it will return TRUE if `username=$username OR password = $password` .
if one of the username or password will be found in table(and `$count === 1` it will return TRUE)
where is my prbolem and how should I solve it?

Comment: According to the documentation, calling "where" twice will produce an AND query. I don't understand what the problem is?

Comment: You mean it's evaluated as `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: Have you tried the *Associative array method*? Which codeigniter version are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$this->db->count_all_results('PM_ADMIN_LIST');
```

is returning the number of rows in the table and ignorning the restrictors above it.

Try:-

```
$this->db->where('username',$username);
$this->db->where('password',$password);
$this->db->from('PM_ADMIN_LIST');
$count = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Also, put some debug in - if you knew what the value of `$count` was then it may have helped you work out that the Active Record query was wrong rather than thinking it was doing an `OR` instead of an `AND`.

Comment: I done it,but I will return same result as my code.
I tried $count = $this->db->where('username',$username)->where('password',$password)->get('PM_ADMIN_LIST')->num_rows();
 too.but It has this problem too.

Comment: The code I posted should work, please post your version of the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use->
$this->db->count_all();
instead of
$this->db->count_all_results();
problem resolved.......

Answer (score -1):

Add second parameter with value `false` in **count_all_results()** function.

```
$this->db->count_all_results('PM_ADMIN_LIST',FALSE);
```